# Getting Java version at runtime

Tags: java, jvm

I need to work around a Java bug in JDK 1.5 which was fixed in 1.6. I'm using the following condition:

```
if (System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.5.")) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Will this work for other JVMs? Is there a better way to check this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

These articles seem to suggest that checking for `1.5` or `1.6` prefix should work, as it follows proper version naming convention.

#### Sun Technical Articles

- [J2SE SDK/JRE Version String Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html)
- [Version 1.5.0 or 5.0?](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/version-5.0.html)

  - "J2SE also keeps the version number 1.5.0 (or 1.5) in some places that are visible only to developers, or where the version number is parsed by programs"

    - "`java.version` system property"
- [Version 1.6.0 Used by Developers](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/version-6.html)

  - "Java SE keeps the version number 1.6.0 (or 1.6) in some places that are visible only to developers, or where the version number is parsed by programs."

    - "`java.version` system property"

Comment: Is there a way to obtain whether it's Oracle or Open?

Comment: Now that the versioning syntax has changed beginning in Java 9, the other answers are more useful.

Comment: To address @JoeC question some years later:  look at some of the other system properties, in particular these six:  `java.runtime.name`, `java.vendor`, `java.vm.{name,vendor}`, `java.vm.specification.{name,vendor}`  I believe the first two may be semi-standardized by the official JVM/JLS spec, and the rest may be sort of standard conventions by now.  Depending on what exactly the use case is in the application, often one or more of those properties can be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 165):

`java.version` is a [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) that exists in every JVM. There are two possible formats for it:

- Java 8 or lower: `1.6.0_23`, `1.7.0`, `1.7.0_80`, `1.8.0_211`
- Java 9 or higher: `9.0.1`, `11.0.4`, `12`, `12.0.1`

Here is a trick to extract the major version: If it is a `1.x.y_z` version string, extract the character at index 2 of the string. If it is a `x.y.z` version string, cut the string to its first dot character, if one exists.

```java
private static int getVersion() {
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
    if(version.startsWith("1.")) {
        version = version.substring(2, 3);
    } else {
        int dot = version.indexOf(".");
        if(dot != -1) { version = version.substring(0, dot); }
    } return Integer.parseInt(version);
}
```

Now you can check the version much more comfortably:

```java
if(getVersion() < 6) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It is ok for 1.5 but 1.6 is not precise as a floating point number.

Comment: FP precision aside, for the OP's needs the code provided should at least be (version > 1.5), not >=.

To the OP: if you use your current String comparison do you need to check below 1.5 too?

Comment: @Ha: Maybe but `double version = 1.6` and `Double.parseDouble("1.6")` should still yield the same bit pattern, right? Since we don't do arithmetics on the number (only a simple compare), even == will work as expected.

Comment: This code results in `java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points`. Instead you want `getVersion` to return the double substring of `version.substring(0, pos - 1)`. (Otherwise you're trying to create a double out of the string "1.7.0" which is not a proper double).

Comment: @ChaimKut: Thanks, fixed. Since the first part of the number is always 1, I'm wondering if it doesn't make sense to skip that and instead return minor version + patch level.

Comment: but soon we will have version 1.1 again... or maybe instead of 1.10 we start with 2.0 [:-)

Comment: In Java 9, there won't be "1." in front. The string will start with "9..."

Comment: In leetcode REPL environment i am getting following exception when trying to run this code: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read")

Comment: @Tarun They probably have a `SecurityManager` installed. Check the documentation how to access system properties in leetcode REPL.

Answer (score 69):

## `Runtime.version()`

Since Java 9, you can use [`Runtime.version()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#version()), which returns a [`Runtime.Version`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.Version.html):

```
Runtime.Version version = Runtime.version();
```

Comment: echo "System.err.print(Runtime.version().major())" | $JDK/bin/jshell 2>&1 > /dev/null

Comment: @judovana Runtime.version().major() is deprecated since Java10, the equivalent is now Runtime.version().feature().

Comment: yes it doesnt works now

Answer (score 64):

What about getting the version from the package meta infos:

```
String version = Runtime.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

Prints out something like:

1.7.0_13

Comment: Wow, that kind of blew my mind. Though in my case, all I wanted was the first two parts of the version so: `Runtime.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion()`

Comment: `Runtime.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` seems to return `null` on JDK9.

Comment: Maybe this only works when it's defined in MANIFEST.MF?

Answer (score 33):

The simplest way (**java.specification.version**):

```
double version = Double.parseDouble(System.getProperty("java.specification.version"));

if (version == 1.5) {
    // 1.5 specific code
} else {
    // ...
}
```

or something like (**java.version**):

```
String[] javaVersionElements = System.getProperty("java.version").split("\\.");

int major = Integer.parseInt(javaVersionElements[1]);

if (major == 5) {
    // 1.5 specific code
} else {
    // ...
}
```

or if you want to break it all up (**java.runtime.version**):

```
String discard, major, minor, update, build;

String[] javaVersionElements = System.getProperty("java.runtime.version").split("\\.|_|-b");

discard = javaVersionElements[0];
major   = javaVersionElements[1];
minor   = javaVersionElements[2];
update  = javaVersionElements[3];
build   = javaVersionElements[4];
```

Comment: your version with `java.runtime.version` is broken for Java 9 (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

Answer (score 13):

Example for Apache Commons Lang:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils;

    Float version = SystemUtils.JAVA_VERSION_FLOAT;

    if (version < 1.4f) { 
        // legacy
    } else if (SystemUtils.IS_JAVA_1_5) {
        // 1.5 specific code
    } else if (SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(1.6f)) {
        // 1.6 compatible code
    } else {
        // dodgy clause to catch 1.4 :)
    }
```

Comment: `version < 1.4f`... What happens when `version = 1.4f`?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right - 1.4f would not be captured in the above example. The example is only demonstrating Apache Commons Lang's constants as an alternative to Java's properties :)

Comment: You can edit the answer and change it to `version <= 1.4f`.. Unfortunately `SystemUtils` does not provide a `isJavaVersionLessThan` method but then (fortunately) you could also put the legacy code in an `else` block, which is cleaner.

Comment: Err... *"dodgy clause to catch 1.4"*? Shouldn't `1.4f` fall back to legacy code?

Comment: I would suggest: `if (SystemUtils.IS_JAVA_1_5) { /* 1.5 specific code */ } else if (SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(1.6f)) { /* modern code */ } else { /* fall back to legacy code */ }`. Specific code above, generic code below, fallback code at the very bottom.

Comment: @ADTC: You are right. Your structure is better than mine. But the reason I want to keep my structure is because people can see that `SystemUtils.JAVA_VERSION_FLOAT` can and/or must be compared with a float literal. That's my only excuse :)

Answer (score 11):

Just a note that in Java 9 and above, the naming convention is different. `System.getProperty("java.version")` returns `"9"` rather than `"1.9"`.

Answer (score 8):

Does not work, need `--pos` to evaluate double:

```
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
    System.out.println("version:" + version);
    int pos = 0, count = 0;
    for (; pos < version.length() && count < 2; pos++) {
        if (version.charAt(pos) == '.') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    --pos; //EVALUATE double

    double dversion = Double.parseDouble(version.substring(0, pos));
    System.out.println("dversion:" + dversion);
    return dversion;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the implementation in [JOSM](https://github.com/openstreetmap/josm/blob/a3a6e8a6b657cf4c5b4c64ea14d6e87be6280d65/src/org/openstreetmap/josm/tools/Utils.java#L1566-L1585):

```
/**
 * Returns the Java version as an int value.
 * @return the Java version as an int value (8, 9, etc.)
 * @since 12130
 */
public static int getJavaVersion() {
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
    if (version.startsWith("1.")) {
        version = version.substring(2);
    }
    // Allow these formats:
    // 1.8.0_72-ea
    // 9-ea
    // 9
    // 9.0.1
    int dotPos = version.indexOf('.');
    int dashPos = version.indexOf('-');
    return Integer.parseInt(version.substring(0,
            dotPos > -1 ? dotPos : dashPos > -1 ? dashPos : 1));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can have dependency to apache utils you can use org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.

```
    System.out.println("Is Java version at least 1.8: " + SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion.JAVA_1_8));
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know another way of checking this, but this: [http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()"](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) implies "java.version" is a standard system property so I'd expect it to work with other JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer from @mvanle, converted to Scala:

`scala> val Array(javaVerPrefix, javaVerMajor, javaVerMinor, _, _) = System.getProperty("java.runtime.version").split("\\.|_|-b")
javaVerPrefix: String = 1
javaVerMajor: String = 8
javaVerMinor: String = 0`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.Version.html#version--

```
 Runtime.version().version()
```

For 17.0.1 it returns [17, 0, 1]
One can use `Runtime.version().version().get(0)` to get the major java version.

Answer (score -1):

In kotlin:

```kotlin
/**
 * Returns the major JVM version, e.g. 6 for Java 1.6, 8 for Java 8, 11 for Java 11 etc.
 */
public val jvmVersion: Int get() = System.getProperty("java.version").parseJvmVersion()

/**
 * Returns the major JVM version, 1 for 1.1, 2 for 1.2, 3 for 1.3, 4 for 1.4, 5
 * for 1.5 etc.
 */
fun String.parseJvmVersion(): Int {
    val version: String = removePrefix("1.").takeWhile { it.isDigit() }
    return version.toInt()
}
```