# Programmatically identifying JDK version of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, java

I have a web application running on Tomcat and JDK. Is it possible to programmatically identify the JDK version Tomcat is running on, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to Tomcat. Each Java program allows to do it, and [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103121/how-to-find-the-jvm-version-from-a-java-program).