# How do I check a clients Java Version?

Tags: java, jar

I want to create an Executable Jar file that when run, checks the currently installed version of Java on that computer and displays it for the user. I have searched online but in vain, I cannot find any code that allows a Jar file to check. I know that the Java website has it ( http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) I can't find a way to replicate it in Java Code. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Note: Sorry if this question is really stupid and has a really simple answer... I just spent half an hour trying to find a solution and I couldn't so I need your help! Thanks

Edit: I don't need the code for displaying it, just to get the version is enough for me thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103121/how-to-find-the-jvm-version-from-a-java-program also, if you're targeting Windows try this -> http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ you can bundle the JVM with it if it is critical or just throw an error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting version of java in runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.getProperty("java.version");`

Comment: Wow so it was so simple, thanks! But I feel really stupid now!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `System.getProperty("java.version");` will give you version of the installed `JRE` which is what you want. Also take a look at other [System properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), you may find some of them also useful.