# How to get java version programmatically with update information

Tags: java, intellij-idea, system-properties

```
$java -version
```

prints like below

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

The info which I am interested in is complete java version, `System.getProperties()` doesn't seem to have that information. It only has the version before `_`, not update information which is `40` in my case.

**EDIT:** When I run the a test code `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version");` prints the complete version. But I am working on a large codebase in which I can't get the same result. I checked the code-base if the property somehow overwritten at some point, but couldn't find anything.

**EDIT_2:** I figured out that `java.version` prints 1.8.0_40 when I manually compile the code with `javac` then run it with `java` on the terminal. However it prints only 1.8.0 when I run it via IntelliJ.

Comment: Kindly check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103121/how-to-find-the-jvm-version-from-a-program

Comment: It may be stupid but are you sure that the Java that version you are checking has any update to show?

Comment: @m.antkowicz yes it has, please see my second edit :)

Answer (score 14):

You can get the complete version using this property:

```
java.runtime.version
```

This is an example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
    }
}
```

On my machine I get the following output:

> 1.8.0_92-b14

If you only want the part before `-`, use the following system property:

```
java.version
```

This will output:

> 1.8.0_92

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use these properties with below code

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        System.out.println("version : "+version);

String vendor = System.getProperty("java.vendor");
        System.out.println("java Vendor : "+vendor);

String vm = System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
        System.out.println("java vm name : "+vm);
```

**Output :**

version : 15

java Vendor : Oracle Corporation

java vm name : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

=======

for more command see attached image