# How to get the current application version in Java 11 Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, java-11

I am unable to get the current application version in my attempt to migrate App Engine to Java 11. In Java 8 I did:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
String version = SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get().split("\\.")[0];
```

However, this AppEngine API is deprecated in Java 11 version of AppEngine. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? I am unable to find this anywhere, there seems to be no documentation on this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I already tried to get in from the metadata endpoint (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/accessing-instance-metadata). This works for the project-id and region, but the documentation does not state anything about the version. Maybe it is not documented, but also accessible this way (it would make sense).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get java version programmatically with update information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934673/how-to-get-java-version-programmatically-with-update-information)

Comment: Do you want to know the exact java version, or the app engine service version?

Comment: I would like to see the AppEngine service version

Answer (score 1):

The information is available in the [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#environment_variables) in the app engine. You should be able to get it through GAE_version environment variable.This is mentioned in the [migration notes for app engine.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#environment_variables)