# How to ensure my Java program does not use the Oracle JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, version

I will develop a Java program for a company where I don't really know whether their IT department will handle things like Java installations correctly, so I would like to ensure that the program I develop for them does not make them require a licence from Oracle.

For this, I would like to find out what JVM would be used to run a Java program without actually running any Java program. I am not sure whether running java -version would be allowed, so I think I can't do it.

I would need to support at least Windows and Mac, but a completely cross-platform approach would certainly be convenient.

Comment: this answer could be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103166/10117689

Comment: Why would license management be your responsibility as a developer?

Comment: Well, the problem is that I can only use that while Java is running, where it is probably already "too late"

Comment: It's not my responsibility, I just don't want to get blamed if they don't have a good licence management (somehow I don't think they have it)

Comment: Why don't you include the java binary with your program?

Comment: That's something I could do additionally, but I guess it wouldn't receive any security updates. In fact, I think I have in mind to ship an OpenJDK JRE with my application, and if I find out that the installed java is not Oracle, I would use it (to benefit from security updates), but if it is Oracle, I use the supplied

Comment: It is not your duty to check that. If that company decides to use the commercial JRE from Oracle, it’s their task to ensure proper licensing, i.e. pay for it. The license conditions are visible to them when they download it. They even have to click on a button saying that they *accept* that license. But, perhaps, they want that, so who are you to deny them running your application in a properly licensed environment?