# Writing forwards-compatible code when an API introduces a new exception type

Tags: java, exception

One problem I've noticed when porting reflection code from Java 8 to Java 9+ is that `setAccessible()` now throws `InaccessibleObjectException` in addition to `SecurityException` when before in Java 8 `InaccessibleObjectException` wasn't an exception type.

What is the *accepted* way to write code that has to catch and handle an exception that it can't know about since it's in a future Java version yet still be compatible with the current version? (In this case the only ancestor class is `RuntimeException`, but that feels like a smell to me personally to write such an all-encompassing `catch`.)

Comment: It sounds like you want forward compatibility, not backward compatibility.

Comment: I've changed the title to reflect the correct definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the runtime for the Java version (as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103121/how-to-find-the-jvm-version-from-a-program)) and use `exception.getClass().getName()` to get the exception class name in a backward-compatible way

In other words

```
  try {
    method.setAccessible();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    String version = (System.getProperty("java.version"))
    String minorVersion = ver.split("\\.")[1];
    if (minorVersion >=9) {
      if (e.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException")) {
        // Handle java 9 reflection access issue
      } else {
        // Handle java 8 runtime exception
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's a valid solution but it seems "syntactically heavy" if you get what I mean. (And by the way, welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Thanks!  Another idea I had was to use `Class.forName(...)` and catch `ClassNotFoundException` but that involves about as much code.  You could of course put the handling code in a static function on a utility class but not sure if that was your concern.

Comment: Technically you'd need to go up the superclass chain. / You don't need to check version. / Handling the runtime exception would be just `throw e;`.

Comment: No need to check for the Java version. But since `InaccessibleObjectException` is not `final` and could have sub-classes, you should check all super-classes of `e` as well.