# What jvm is actually used on jenkins script console?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins claims that "This execution happens in the agent JVM", but when I use this script on script console, I see the next result:

```
def proc = 'java -version'.execute()
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(10000)
println "out> $sout"
println "err> $serr"
```

`java version "1.7.0"`

Then I connect to the same agent via putty, use `java -version` on conlose and get `openjdk version "1.8.0_272"`

Why?

Comment: Jenkins is using its own version of the JVM, not the one found on the path as specified by your shell's environment variable.

Comment: So what versions it uses when it executes a pipeline script?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but can probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5103121/2422776

Comment: Is it possible to change jenkins jvm?