# Identify Java version of a running application

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, java-8

I have installed Java 7 Update 45 and Java 8 Update 25 in parallel. I am experiencing some text rendering issues in JavaFX which should be fixed in Java 8 Update 25, so I wonder which Java version the application is currently on.

Is there a way to check which version of Java an application uses?

What I have tried:

- I searched the Internet and found StackOverflow's answer to the question [Checking the version of JRE used during run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079831/checking-the-version-of-jre-used-during-run-time). However, I want to check the version without modifying the source code (e.g. I have no source code)
- I searched on StackOverflow and found no additional answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using Task Manager

1. Start Windows Task Manager.
2. On the "Applications" tab, select your application
3. Open the context menu, choose "Go to process". This should be a `javaw.exe`.
4. Open the context menu, choose "Open file location". This opens Explorer and selects `javaw.exe`
5. Open the context menu, choose "Properties".
6. Go to the "Details" tab to see the version number

### Using Process Explorer

1. Start [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
2. Drag the crosshair over your application to select the process
3. Configure the columns (View/Select columns...) and check "Version" on the "Process Image" tab.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Command Line**

```
C:\>java -version
```

**Output**

> java version "1.7.0_55"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime    Environment (build  1.7.0_55-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM    (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Won't this only list the default Java version? What if an application started from the Windows start menu is configured to run a different (older) version of Java?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to control panel
2. Type "java" in search box
3. Click java
4. Click on "About..." button in "General" tab
5. Check the currently running software version, which is being pointed
6. Then go to "Java" tab in the same window, and make sure that Java 8 is checked.
7. If you are unable to see the installed Java 8 in the Java tab, uninstall all the Java versions. Install the versions from higher to lower one by one (Java 8 to Java 7).
8. Don't forget to set the environment variables

This will surely solve your problem.