# Java version validation

Tags: java

I need to validate java version. I use

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

How to simple parse that to know for example that installed JRE is in min. `1.6.0_18` version ? I wonder is that naming convention of java version is standard.

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime

Comment: That answer is about check main version 1.5 vs 1.6. I need to validate  more (`.0_18`, `.0-beta1` etc)

Comment: @marioosh i guess my answer will do what you want, just leave a comment if unclear or something

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is naming convention. You can find it from [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/versioning_naming.html). And more fresh information about version 6 can be found from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/version-6-141920.html).

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I see that is more complicated. Do You have some idea how to parse that to verify installed version ?

Comment: @marioosh take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is as far as i know the naming convention of java Versions, so just use the `System.getProperty("java.version")` as you are already doing, and check the String by using stringTokenizer if the minimum required jre is installed.

Edit: i wrote Stringbuilder in the beginning, of cource i meant stringtokenizer.

With the Stringtokenizer you can get Substrings of a String separated by a defined Symbol, and kind of iterate through the String. You may need a second stringtokenizer, the first separating the Strting by "." and than for the last Substring one separating by "_". Take a lool [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

You could do it like this:
(of cource you could also do it over a loop, an checking with hasMoreTokens() and so on, but you dont need in this case, because you know exactly what the string looks like)

```
String[] versionArray = new String[4];
String version = System.getProperty("java.version"); 
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(version,".");
versionArray[1] = st1.nextToken();
versionArray[2] = st1.nextToken();
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(st1.nextToken(),"_");
versionArray[3] = st2.nextToken();
versionArray[4] = st2.nextToken();
```

After it in the versionArray would be with your example ["1"]["6"]["0"]["18"] and you can do your comparison on this...

Comment: Do u mean System.getPerperty("java.version").Please make it correct.

Comment: @JDeveloper uhm, no i mean `public static String getProperty(String key)` as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)