# Tag In Project POM To Close My Java Application If JRE 1.6 Is Not Found?

Tags: java, pom.xml, runtime-compilation

I have an application compiled in Java. I build my code through Maven.
I want a tag in my project POM, so that if JRE 1.6 is not found in the system, it should not allow my Java application to launch.

Can I get any help with regard to this ?

Comment: Why hard fix on a 1.6 jre? The 1.7 jre should have no problems, and the 1.5 would not run it anyway if it is compiled on 1.6..

Comment: My java application only supports 1.6 jre due to some other dependency. I want it to function in a way that if the jre version other than 1.6 is picked during launch, it should kill the process.

Comment: The "runtime" configuration inside the POM does not control the execution of your program. It only controls building of a runnable artefact. Once you application is built, it's out of Maven's control.

Comment: Any idea if I can bundle the "required execution environment" with the project POM to jre 1.6 ?

Comment: I have both jre 1.6 and jre 1.7. if we build our code with jre 1.6, it gets build. But when we launch it, it launches with jre 1.7. is not there any way where since it gets built by jre 1.6, it should launch with jre 1.6 if it is available ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to read this:

http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html

```
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-versions</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>2.0.6</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
                **<requireJavaVersion>
                  <version>1.5</version>
                </requireJavaVersion>**
                <requireOS>
                  <family>unix</family>
                </requireOS>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Lokesh.
I want to actually find out a way if the application can be stopped from launching if the intended version of JRE is not found in the machine.

Comment: I need to stop the application from being launched at run-time if the JRE picked is not 1.6.
Any idea regarding that ?

Comment: This might help you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application as

```
java -version:1.6 -jar app.jar
```

it won't start if JRE is not 1.6

or check JRE version programmatically as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (!System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.6")) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal JRE version");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I add something in the Project POM so that when I click on the executable, it kills the application if the JRE version used is not 1.6.. ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, pom is not used at runtime. You can check java version programmatically in your app main as System.getProperty("java.version") and exit it it's not 1.6

Comment: Any idea if I can bundle the "required execution environment" with the project POM to jre 1.6 ?

Comment: Only that you can add Java-Version: 1.6 entry to MANIFEST.MF with maven-jar-plugin, but you will have to read it manually

Comment: One quick question, I have both jre 1.6 and jre 1.7.
if we build our code with jre 1.6, it gets build. But when we launch it, it launches with jre 1.7.
is not there any way where since it gets built by jre 1.6, it should launch with jre 1.6 if it is available ?