# Is it ok to use javax.lang.model.SourceVersion to determine the JRE version?

Tags: java

Is it ok to use [javax.lang.model.SourceVersion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html) to determine the JRE version?

If it is, which one is preffered?

```
int version = SourceVersion.latest().ordinal();
// or
int version = SourceVersion.latestSupported().ordinal();
```

Bonus points to whomever explains when SourceVersion#latest() and SourceVersion#LatestSupported() can differ.

PS. I am aware of [Getting Java version at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SourceVersion.latest()` returns  latest source version that can be modeled.

`SourceVersion.latestSupported()` Returns the latest source version fully supported by the current execution environment.  {@code RELEASE_5} or later

When I checked the sourcecode at [java 7 sourceVersion srcCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.java)

following snippet explains the internal behavior

```
public static SourceVersion latest() { 
 return RELEASE_7;
}

private static SourceVersion More ...getLatestSupported() {
       try {
           String specVersion = System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
           if ("1.7".equals(specVersion))
               return RELEASE_7;
            else if ("1.6".equals(specVersion))
                return RELEASE_6;
        } catch (SecurityException se) {}

        return RELEASE_5;
  }
```

Hope it clarifies your doubts

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question-

> when SourceVersion#latest() and SourceVersion#LatestSupported() can differ.

As you are aware by now that the **latestSupported** is derived from the system property **java.specification.version**.

So for example if you are running your application on JAVA 8, then:

> SourceVersion#latest() will alwasy be RELEASE_8

SourceVersion#LatestSupported() could be any of the following:

1. RELEASE_5
2. RELEASE_6
3. RELEASE_7
4. RELEASE_8

based on the **java.specification.version** in the the jar/war. Technically this can be a user defined value and is very useful when you develop an api (Which can be distributed to various other developers/applications)