# Setting required Java version for .jar file to run with?

Tags: java, version

I have a program that cannot run as long as Java 8 is installed on my system. Can I specify which version of java that should run that specific .jar file, so I don't have to uninstall it each time I'm going to run the program?

Comment: `I have a program that cannot run as long as Java 8 is installed on my system` I find this very hard to believe that having Java 8 any where on a system could cause, a Java 6 or 7 program to not run.

Comment: It also shouldn´t cause any Error Messages until it hits a part with unknown classes, expression or methods for prior Java Versions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It does. I'll post a screenshot when I get to the computer.

Answer (score 1):

you could check the Java Version at the start of your main class and exit it if a version lower then 1.8 is installed.

take a look here [Getting Java version at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime)

Comment: plus 1, I would add a message explaining this before exiting.

Comment: @KevinEsche I have not programmed the program. It's a game launcher (ATLauncher) which launches different minecraft modpacks.