# Determine java version used to call a program

Tags: java

I'm trying to determine inside an application what is the Java version used to call a JAR.

I saw some solutions talking about `System.getProperty(java.version)`, but what if the user have different versions of Java, and the command is like this:

```
C:\Absolute\Path\To\Java\1.5\java -jar something.jar
```

Is there any way to know the real Java version?

Comment: actually, "System.getProperty(java.version)" should return the version of the executing java VM. Have you tested it?

Comment: Do you want to get the java version from inside your `something.jar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `System.getProperty("java.version")`. This will give you the version of the *currently running* JVM as a `String`, And you can then check for a prefix like `1.5` or `1.6`, and you have the version of Java.

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime), and the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for `System.getProperty(...)`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`System.getProperty("java.version")` will always give you what version of java is currently running the code that called that statement, no matter how many different versions of java exist on the system.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperty("java.version")
```