# How to write a Java unit test impacted by a JDK bug

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, java-7

I recently discovered that one of my units tests fails due to a bug in the JDK i.e. [JDK-8080774](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080774)

What is the best way of writing a conditional unit test – which checks the output one way for JDK versions where the bug fix is present and a different way when the bug fix is absent?

In case of JDK bug [8080774](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8080774) – it is not fixed at all in JDK 6 or older, it is fixed in JDK version 7u91 or higher as well as in JDK version [8u60](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u60-bugfixes-2620228.html) or higher

I already considered parsing the output of `System.getProperty("java.version")` but I am looking for a better/more elegant solution, if possible.

For example [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.html) has `SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast()` method but it does not have enough granularity.

Comment: Why are you still using old, insecure, buggy versions of the JDK?  Is there any way to get everything current and avoid a whole bunch of issues?

Comment: @Brian The JDK upgrade process is managed by the production support team - outside my control

Comment: If this is for production, your code needs to work around the bug, so you should test that your code produces the correct output on all versions. It would be very odd to have your tests verify that, yes, it does produce the incorrect output in the versions of Java that have this bug.

Comment: I don't know what's not elegant about parsing the actual Java version when the test should act different based on the Java version.

Comment: @Gimby Parsing a string and dealing with all sorts of corner cases seems to me like reinventing the wheel

Comment: Note: it is apparently possible to change the default date formatting, see: http://www.coderanch.com/t/482904/java/java/setting-custom-Date-format-globally

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT - Posted before the question was clearly mentioning this**

As Brian pointed out, you need to get the latest stable version of JDK as much as possible.

However, you can get the VM version by fetching `java.version` property at runtime.

Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime) for more information

Comment: I already considered parsing the output of System.getProperty("java.version") but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: That was not in the question at all :)

Comment: No worries.. You sure you checked the post? There are other ways too!

Comment: I checked this post and any remotely relevant posts on SO already e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java ; most people would go with writing (an imperfect) parsing routine.

Comment: I've done this in the past and had perfectly acceptable (for an imperfect situation) results.