# smartcard probing with different SC families : command to clean the SC state

Tags: java, smartcard

I wish to read some basic info from a bunch of smartcard from different vendors, different usage, different APDUs.
For example : national identification smartcard, EMV (payment), cellphone SIM, javacard, etc ...

I wrote a Java application.
Let me call the SC families A B C D E and with the same names the 5 subroutines, each one with the correct APDUs to read the basic info for one specific family of SC.

Unfortunately the order I issue the routines biases the successful results.

Example : with the subroutine order A B C D E, I can read SC of type A B C D, not E.

If I change the execution order to E A B C D, I can read E but now I fail with SC of type C.

I understand : some SC discard foreign APDUs ... other SC "hangs".

Is there a basic command to clean the state of smartcard ( and reader ) ?

So the order of execution of the subroutines doesn't change the output ?

A reset B reset C reset D reset etc...

Is it ATR ? Is it mandatory on each kind of SC ?

Comment: That should not happen. What card reader are you using? Did you observe same behaviour with a different card reader?

Comment: Yes, two different card readers. Disregarding the specific tests : which is the universal way to reset the reader and the card state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Card.disconnect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/Card.html#disconnect%28boolean%29) method to reset card (beware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40460516/5128464)).

But (IMHO) the best way is to use card ATR (as given by [Card.getATR()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/Card.html#getATR--)) for guessing the correct card family (if possible). This way is also much faster. I used this approach for a demo handling several distinct contactless card products and it worked very well.

---

Some additional (random) notes:

- Study the documentation for all families -- definitely there must be a reason for such behavior. Try to skip some subroutines and/or their APDU commands to pin it down.
- In addition some APDUs might cause problems when sent accidentally (e.g. locked secret codes or locked authentication attempts). You should know what you are doing.
- Most of product families have some way to be reliably detected -- see the documentation if you have it.
- If any previously called subroutine uses `SELECT` to change selected application/file and succeeds it stays selected. Consider using explicit `SELECT` at the beginning of each of your subroutine (e.g. select expected AID or master file).
- DESFire cards leave native mode and enter wrapped mode upon receiving non-native command APDU (which probably is not your case as you usually ISO wrap commands when using javax.smartcardio).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you described sounds really strange since a smartcard reader should not keep states between different smart cards.

However, I don't know any universal command to reboot smart card readers. For example `HID OMNIKEY` readers, you can reboot with proprietary APDU `FF 70 07 6B 08 A2 06 A1 04 A9 02 83 00 00` (see [here](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/plt-03092_a.0_omnikey_5022_sw_dev_guide.pdf) [7.6.3], though this guide says it is for OMNIKEY 5022 readers, it works for many more OMNIKEY readers). So for your reader you will have to research the internet for similar proprietary APDU.

Keep in mind that a reader reboot also most likely will cause the USB reader to re-enumerate.