# Get card type from ATR

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

When I scan my card with springcard reader I need to get  if this card is one of those types: CTS or CD_97 or ISO_A or ISO_B or FRD
How can I get those types from ATR?

Those are some ATR examples, I am getting:

**Navigo**:
`3B 88 80 01 00 00 00 00 00 71 81 00 F9`

**Técély**:
`3B 8F 80 01 80 5A 0A 01 01 20 03 11 10 1D 86 BC 82 90 00 C9`

**Oura**:
`3B 8F 80 01 80 5A 0A 01 02 20 03 11 03 53 52 A2 82 90 00 5D`

**Citycard**:
`3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 02 00 00 00 00 69`

Is there any detailed explanation of how we can get those types from ATR?

I am using SpringCard to read cards: http://files.springcard.com/pub/pmd841p-fa.pdf

I was able to find a part of the solution in page 27 and 28[image]
[image]
http://files.springcard.com/pub/%5bpma13205-bd%5d_Smart_Readers_and_RFID_Scanners_Template_System.pdf

I still need to finc the command to get OPT REGISTER

Comment: As far as I know there is no global ATR registry, or a registry of the ATR historical bytes. Looking at the historical bytes within an ATR is probably the best way of distinguishing cards though (at a low level anyway).

Comment: The ATR tool from [pcsc-tools](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/) is a good starting point. I guess you mean ISO 14443 type A and B. Not only, that this information is not visible from the ATR, you wont get the but an ATQB or ATS respectively depending on the used protocol.

Comment: So you think this is no possible to find those types CTS or CD_97 or ISO_A or ISO_B or FRD using ATR?
We will never be sure about the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the *"OPT register"* -- as far as I understand you set this register to control the way how SpringCard's Template System (optionally) encodes card family into its output. My bet is you do not want to use their Template System at all...

---

To get information about generic card technology/family use the following `GET DATA` command to get PIX.SS and PIX.NN (see chapter 2.2.1):

```
FF CA F1 00 00
```

First byte in response is PIX.SS (see chapter 5.1.4):

> 0x00 -> No information given
>   0x01 -> ISO 14443 A, level 1
>   0x02 -> ISO 14443 A, level 2
>   0x03 -> ISO 14443 A, level 3 or 4 (and Mifare)
>   0x05 -> ISO 14443 B, level 1
>   0x06 -> ISO 14443 B, level 2
>   0x07 -> ISO 14443 B, level 3 or 4
>   0x09 -> ICODE 1
>   0x0B -> ISO 15693

The following two bytes contain PIX.NN (see chapter 5.1.5):

> 0x0001 -> NXP Mifare Standard 1k
>   0x0002 -> NXP Mifare Standard 4k
>   0x0003 -> NXP Mifare UltraLight + Other Type 2 NFC Tags with a capacity <= 64 bytes
>   0x0006 -> ST MicroElectronics SR176
>   0x0007 -> ST MicroElectronics SRI4K, SRIX4K, SRIX512, SRI512, SRT512
>   0x000A -> Atmel AT88SC0808CRF
>   0x000B -> Atmel AT88SC1616CRF
>   0x000C -> Atmel AT88SC3216CRF
>   0x000D -> Atmel AT88SC6416CRF
>   0x0012 -> Texas Intruments TAG IT
>   0x0013 -> ST MicroElectronics LRI512
>   0x0014 -> NXP ICODE SLI
>   0x0016 -> NXP ICODE1
>   0x0021 -> ST MicroElectronics LRI64
>   0x0024 -> ST MicroElectronics LR12
>   0x0025 -> ST MicroElectronics LRI128
>   0x0026 -> NXP Mifare Mini
>   0x002F -> Innovision Jewel
>   0x0030 -> Innovision Topaz (NFC Forum type 1 tag)
>   0x0034 -> Atmel AT88RF04C
>   0x0035 -> NXP ICODE SL2
>   0x003A -> NXP Mifare UltraLight C + Other Type 2 NFC Tags with a capacity > 64 bytes
>   0xFFA0 -> Generic/unknown 14443-A card
>   0xFFA1 -> Kovio RF barcode
>   0xFFB0 -> Generic/unknown 14443-B card
>   0xFFB1 -> ASK CTS 256B
>   0xFFB2 -> ASK CTS 512B
>   0xFFB3 -> Pre-standard ST MicroElectronics SRI 4K
>   0xFFB4 -> Pre-standard ST MicroElectronics SRI X512
>   0xFFB5 -> Pre-standard ST MicroElectronics SRI 512
>   0xFFB6 -> Pre-standard ST MicroElectronics SRT 512
>   0xFFB7 -> Inside Contactless PICOTAG/PICOPASS
>   0xFFB8 -> Generic Atmel AT88SC / AT88RF card
>   0xFFC0 -> Calypso card using the Innovatron protocol
>   0xFFD0 -> Generic ISO 15693 from unknown manufacturer
>   0xFFD1 -> Generic ISO 15693 from EMMarin (or Legic)
>   0xFFD2 -> Generic ISO 15693 from ST MicroElectronics, block number on 8 bits
>   0xFFD3 -> Generic ISO 15693 from ST MicroElectronics, block number on 16 bits
>   0xFFFF -> Virtual card (test only)

Please pay attention to the following note regarding PIX.NN values starting with 0xFF (SpringCard proprietary codes):

> The cards in this list are not referenced by PC/SC specification at the date of writing. In case they are added to the specification,
>   the future firmware versions will have to use the new value. It is therefore advised not to check those values in the applications, as
>   they are likely to be removed in the future.

And a note about PIX.NN availability:

> Note: PIX.NN is specified for memory cards only. Even if the GET DATA instruction allows to
>   retrieve PIX.NN even for micro-processor based cards (smartcards), the returned value is
>   unspecified and shall not be used to identify the card.

Disclaimer: I no longer have access to SpringCard reader so I can't test it with my cards, but given [the documentation](http://files.springcard.com/pub/pmd841p-fa.pdf) it should work this way.

---

I was dealing with a very similar problem (processing different cards, somewhat mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446911/5128464)) in the past and the most effective approach was (given my "mix" of cards):

- Use ATR value to create "candidate list" (in many cases ATR value led to a single card scheme candidate)
- If there are more candidates consider the following ways to confirm one of them:

  - technology-specific "directory service" (e.g. MAD, Get Application IDs, PSE/PPSE, PTSE...)
  - trial-and-error application selection (which might be faster than using a directory service if candidate list is very short)
  - (as a least resort) proprietary card scheme detection

This approach assumes that you know all possible ATR values for used cards -- if not you would have to replace/combine it with card technology/family detection described above.

---

Note: pcsc-tools ATR list mentioned in comments is available [here](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/smartcard_list.txt) and [here](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pcsc-tools/blob/master/smartcard_list.txt) (I am not sure which one is canonical)

Good luck!

Comment: I will test it , thank you for the detailed answer ;)

Comment: @haythemsouissi CTS should give PIX.NN of `0xFFB1` and `0xFFB2`.

Comment: thanks @vlp 
one last thing please , any idea for Calypso card?
:)

Comment: @haythemsouissi Linked manual gives some hints in a note inside section 5.1.1.c. (page 60) -- you should get PIX.NN of `0xFFC0` (Innovatron) or a generic T=CL card (probably one of 14443-B variants). If given generic T=CL card you should attempt to "Select Application" to verify it's presence (which is in line with my answer)...I can't help with Calypso specific details as they are not publicly available...Good luck!

Comment: 0xFFC0 -> Calypso card using the Innovatron protocol 
do we have only Calypso that use Innovatron? we don't have other Calypso that use other protocols? Sorry I am not an expert :)

Comment: @haythemsouissi (Sorry I missed it was a question) -- As far as I understand Innovatron protocol was used before ISO 14443 was standardized and ISO14443B was heavily inspired by it (but is different because of some patents held by Innovatron) -- please verify those thoughts...But I would definitely be very cautious as SpringCard's documents do warn about cards that talk both protocols and randomly pick one to be used (a viable solution to this might be to disable Innovatron protocol at all -- see section 3.5.1). It all depends on your use-case -- that you did not specify (but I assume that...

Comment: ...you want to 'do-something-more' with the card after you detected which card it is -- so you will probably need to select some card application as a first step and realize that this step might be used as a part of card detection routine...and don't worry -- neither am I an expert...PS: It is very difficult (almost impossible) to achieve anything with smartcards without proper documentation...Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169115/discussion-between-vlp-and-haythem-souissi).

Answer (score 0):

you can find here spring card answer, sorry but they answered me in Frensh langage, so if there is anything not clear , put it in your comment:

### ATR

1- Envoyer d'abord FF CA FA 00 :
- Avez-vous au moins 14 octets, et les octets 7-11 sont-ils : A0 00 00 03 06 ?
    -> Si oui, alors vous êtes sur une carte à logique câblée, Il faut récupérer le PIX.SS et le PIX.NN (octets 12-13-14 de la réponse) et retrouver la techno de la carte selon les paragraphes 4.1.4 et 4.1.5. La détection de la technologie s'arrête là. Vous pouvez envoyer la commande décrite dans NUM_PROTOCOL pour connaître le numéro protocolaire de la carte.
    -> Si non, alors vous êtes sur une "vraie" carte à puce. Envoyer la commande décrite dans NUM_PROTOCOL

### NUM_PROTOCOL

2- Envoyer FF CA 00 00, et analyser le nombre d'octets dans la réponse :
- réponse sur 7 ou 11 octets: la carte est forcément en ISO A, la réponse est l'UID de la carte. L'algo peut s'arrêter là si vous n'avez pas besoin de plus de détail
- réponse sur 4 octets : c'est le numéro protocolaire. 2 options :
  * si vous avez détecté que c'est une carte à logique câblée à l'étape précédente, alors l'algo peut s'arrêter là si vous n'avez pas besoin de plus de détail
  * Si vous êtes sur une carte à puce, alors il faut envoyer la commande COMPLETE_ID
- réponse sur un nombre d'octet différent : on est forcément sur de la logique câblée (ou carte à mémoire), dont la techno est déja identifiée. La réponse correspond au numéro protocolaire.  L'algo peut s'arrêter là si vous n'avez pas besoin de plus de détail

### COMPLETE_ID

3- On n'arrive ici que quand la carte est une carte avec une "vraie" puce (DONC : pas une carte à mémoire, ni une carte à logique câblée)
Envoyer FF CA F0 00 et analyser le nombre d'octets dans la réponse:
-11 ou 12 octets: c'est forcément de l'ISO B - la valeur obtenue est l'ATQB - le numéro protocolaire a été obtenu à l'étape suivante / la carte est identifiée
- résultat sur un nombre d'octets différent :  vérifier si cela correspond à 3 octets suivi du numéro protocolaire obtenu à la commande précédente
    a) si oui, c'est de l'ISO A - les deux premiers octets sont l'ATQA, et le troisième est le SAK (le reste forme l'UID)
    b) si non alors on a reçu le REPGEN, la carte répond sur le protocole INNOVATRON (le PUPI a été obtenu à l'étape  précédente).

Avec cela, normalement, vous devriez être en mesure de reconnaître toutes vos cartes.